# What is the best way to display data of a text file using the fetch function of Java Script in Flask by by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, python, database, flask

I am trying to click a button which opens a text file `raw_vlans`.  I am using `Flask` and `Bootstrap` and at the same time I am using the `fetch` function from `Java Script` to do the loading of the text file data. But nothing displays when I click on the button. When I click on the view function, I notice the following: `"GET /app/js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Here is the html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}

    <h1>Router: {{ router.routername }}</h1>
    
    {% if router.about_router %} <p>About router: {{ router.about_router }}</p> {% endif %}
    
    {% if router == current_user %}
        <p> <a href="{{ url_for('edit_router') }}"> Edit Router </a> </p>
    {% endif %}
    <h1 style="color: green;"> Vlan Configurations </h1>

        <div class="container">

            <button id="button1">Load  vlan Data</button>

            <div id="result"></div>

            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            
        </div>

        <style>
            .container {
                margin: 40px;
            }
        </style>
```

The triggered Java Script code when the button is clicked is stored in `app.js` and contains the following.

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', loadTxt);

//Load txt
function loadTxt() {
    fetch('show_vlan')
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

The structure of the applications is shown below:

```
vlans/
     app/
         templates/
               base.html
               index.html
               router.html
        js/
           app.js
        forms.py
        __init__.py
        models.py
        routes.py
     show_vlans
```

I need to understand when the button is not working and the reason why the view function has a `404 error` in the console when fetching the `app/app.js` file.

Comment: You read the data from the file, but the data you write to the database is from the form?

Comment: @snakecharmerb. Thank you for the hint. What changes do I need to make in reading the file and storing its contents into the database through the form? Or I do not need the form at all.

Comment: If the file is on the local filesystem you don't need the form, just use the data directly.

Comment: Good, imagine that is what I had done and got the answer. Thank you a million times @snakecharmerb

Comment: Added ajax as advised else where, but still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when using flask, I needed to have a `static` folder, otherwise flask will not recognize the path. Therefore, the `js` folder should be insider the `static` folder, and the path:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

changed to:

```
 <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
```